# WordPress function inject php code at every get_post loop to decide if post gets displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I have written a simple php code that checks user roles against post custom fields to decide if a post gets displayed in the list or not.

If i write the code in a manually post loop and made an if around the post structure it works just fine.

Now i want to pack it in a function to run automatic at every get_post but here my wordpress knowledge is at its end ...

I have only found examples to prevent a post from displaying based on categories.

The code it self is not very relevant ...
Only if the $ure_display variable will be set to true = display the post in the list otherwise hide the post.

The Code:

```
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$get_roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
$cust = get_post_custom($post_id);
$ure_roles = $cust["ure_content_for_roles"][0];
$ure_flag = $cust["ure_prohibit_allow_flag"][0];
$ure_display = "false";
$permchk = 0;
            
foreach ($get_roles as $value) {
 if (str_contains($ure_roles, $value)) {
     $permchk = 1;
}
}
            
if ($permchk == 1 && $ure_flag == 2){
$ure_display = "true";
echo $ure_display;
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help me with a example.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH !

Comment: The `get_post` function (you did really mean that one, yes, and not `get_posts`?) does not appear to execute _any_ filters (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/#source), so there isn't really a way to manipulate what that function does from the outside.

Comment: You are right.
Meanwhile i found out there is a  pre_get_posts hook to do such things ...
Here is an example with categories but i dont know how to change the code:
https://crunchify.com/best-way-to-prevent-posts-from-a-particular-category-to-be-displayed-in-wordpress-loop/

Comment: You're dealing with post meta data, so you will need to add a meta query then - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Answer (score 0):

To automate the execution of your PHP code for every '**get_post**' loop in WordPress, you can utilize the '**the_post hook**', which is fired before displaying each post. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
  function custom_post_display_logic($post) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $get_roles = (array) $user->roles;
    $cust = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $ure_roles = $cust["ure_content_for_roles"][0];
    $ure_flag = $cust["ure_prohibit_allow_flag"][0];
    $ure_display = false;
    $permchk = 0;

    foreach ($get_roles as $value) {
        if (strpos($ure_roles, $value) !== false) {
            $permchk = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($permchk == 1 && $ure_flag == 2) {
        $ure_display = true;
    }

    return $ure_display;
}

add_action('the_post', 'custom_post_display_logic');
```

This function hooks into '**the_post**' and applies your custom display logic for each post. It will return '**true**' if the post should be displayed and '**false**' if it should be hidden based on your conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much !
But if it hooks to the post itself it will not prevent from displaying the post in the post loop (like category pages) or did i get something wrong here ?
I have try to implement the code but sadly with no luck ... 
I also tried to empty the post array or wpdie if $ure_display is not true to prevent the post from display in the list ... sadly no luck.

Thank you very much !